# How can I call a method with weaker side effect guarantee?

Tags: checker-framework

I've got this from the Lock checker:

```
Error:(52, 30) java: [method.guarantee.violated] @ReleasesNoLocks method proc() calls method unfree() with a weaker @MayReleaseLocks side effect guarantee
```

I could post the code but it doesn't matter. I just don't understand the documentation about invocation of side-effect methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks something like this:

```
@ReleasesNoLocks
void proc() {
  ...
  unfree();  // line 52
  ...
}

void unfree() {
  // arbitrary code that might include someLock.unlock();
}
```

The documentation for
[`@ReleasesNoLocks`](https://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/api/org/checkerframework/checker/lock/qual/ReleasesNoLocks.html) says:

> The method, and all the methods it calls, maintain a strictly nondecreasing lock hold count

The `@ReleasesNoLocks` annotation on method `proc` promises that method `proc` will not release any locks.  However, method `unfree` might release some locks (because it isn't annotated as `@ReleasesNoLocks`).  If `unfree` releases a lock, then `proc` violates its specification.  That's what the Lock Checker's message is saying (in a terse way).

There are three possibilities for what happens at run time:

1. `unfree` really does release a lock.  In this case, your code is buggy and the Lock Checker has told you about it!  The annotation `@ReleasesNoLocks` on `proc` is false.  You need to remove that annotation or change `unfree` to not release any locks.
2. `unfree` never releases any lock.  In this case, you should annotate `unfree` as `@ReleasesNoLocks`.  At that point, the Lock Checker will be able to verify that `proc`'s implementation satisfies its specification, so it will no longer issue the warning.
3. `unfree` sometimes releases a lock, and sometimes does not release a lock.  You know that the particular call within the body of `proc` doesn't release a lock.  In this case, you should write a `@SuppressWarnings("method.guarantee.violated")` annotation on line 52 of your source code.    The key "method.guarantee.violated" appears in the error message. I recommend adding a comment explaining how you know this fact, as well, so that in the future you know why you wrote the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation.